# Laravel Vuejs Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Login is not defined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to use vue-router in a CRUD app I've followed in a tutorial. The links showing up but I get this error: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: Login is not defined

[image: Error]

I already imported vue-router in my app.js and laid out the routes in my routes.js file. Yet the error still pops out. I've been searching for this error for a while now and can't seem to find out what's causing this.

app.js:

```js
require('./bootstrap');

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

Vue.component('navbar', require('./components/Navbar.vue').default);
Vue.component('customers', require('./components/Customers.vue').default);
Vue.component('login', require('./components/auth/Login.vue').default);


const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
         { path: '/login', component: Login },
         { path: '/register', component: Register }
    ]
})



const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    router: router
})
```

routes.js:

```js
import App from './App'
import Login from './components/auth/Login'
import Logout from './components/auth/Logout'
import Register from './components/auth/Register'

export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/customers',
    name: 'customers',
    component: App,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: Login,
    meta: {
      requiresVisitor: true,
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    name: 'register',
    component: Register,
    meta: {
      requiresVisitor: true,
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/logout',
    name: 'logout',
    component: Logout
  }
]

export default routes
```

Thanks!

Comment: What tutorial are you following? It's a bit of a mess with the mixed use of `require` and `import`. I recommend following the official vue-router guide ~ https://router.vuejs.org/guide/

Comment: The main problem is the routes.js isn't being used, and the app,js looks like it has some old boilerplate routes

Comment: Any reason to be mixing require calls with import syntax? That shouldn’t be necessary...

Comment: @Phil Its this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJ6PD_jBtU0&t=1s
I'll try that link too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like all the other answers, there are so many things wrong with this code.

Firstly, there is a routes.js file, but it's not being used.

I've created a sandbox version of your code https://codesandbox.io/s/z22rx97z24 to show you a working version of the router/app.

What's changed?

Firstly, you should export an instance of the vue router in the routes.js not just define a const. This is the recommended way of routing in Vue.

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";

import App from "./App";
import Login from "./components/auth/Login";
import Logout from "./components/auth/Logout";
import Register from "./components/auth/Register";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/customers",
      name: "customers",
      component: App,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/login",
      name: "login",
      component: Login,
      meta: {
        requiresVisitor: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/register",
      name: "register",
      component: Register,
      meta: {
        requiresVisitor: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/logout",
      name: "logout",
      component: Logout
    }
  ]
});
```

Secondly, you import that instance into app.js and assign into the router property of the Vue instance.

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import router from "./routes";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  router: router
});
```

You keep components out of your app.js where possible. This allows you to do things like on-demand resource loading inside your router.js etc.

Comment: _"This is the recommended way of routing in Vue"_  not really. Functionally, it's identical

Comment: I'll try this out, thanks. Still kinda new to vue-router.

Comment: There's one in every crowd @Phil - go build a new vue project from the CLI (the people who created the framework) and select vue-router as a dependency during setup. You'll find this is how they boilerplate it - so yeah, I'd say it's the recommended (not the only) way of doing it.

Comment: @Phil - also thanks for the edit, I didn't realise you could add the language specific marker. cheers for that

Comment: For some reason, Google's code-prettify doesn't think blocks beginning with `import` are JS

Comment: I tried this out but now i am getting this error:
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <navbar> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

(found in <Root>)

i'm also using custom tags in my welcome.blade.php like:
<div id="app">
                <navbar></navbar>
                <div class="container">
                    <customers></customers>
                </div>
            </div>
Is there a way to avoid this? Thanks.

Comment: @Subaru - that's really a new stackoverflow question. I only dealt with your router issue. The component stuff and raw tags etc is completely separate.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have mixed up some code in your `app.js` file.

Specifically, your problem is here...

```js
  { path: '/login', component: Login },
```

You don't have a `Login` symbol defined anywhere. You're also defining some global components which I'm not sure you want to do.

What I think you want is to remove all this...

```js
Vue.component('login', require('./components/auth/Login.vue').default);

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
         { path: '/login', component: Login },
         { path: '/register', component: Register }
    ]
})
```

and replace it with

```js
import { routes } from './routes'

const router = new VueRouter({ routes })
```

---

I'm also a little suspicious of

```js
require('./bootstrap');
```

but you haven't said what `bootstrap` is so I'll leave that with you to figure out.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but now i am getting this error:

Uncaught TypeError: routes.forEach is not a function

Comment: @Subaru I didn't realise you were exporting the symbol `routes` instead of a default. I've updated my answer but check out [Trent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56123774/283366), it's more comprehensive

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
import routes from './routes.js'
const router = new VueRouter({routes})
```

To your actual error. Yes you imported Login in your routes.js file, but at the error shows you, it isn't defined in app.js. You need to import things in every file you want to use it in.